# Implementing a MessageBodyReader for an enum

Tags: java, enums, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a new MessageBodyReader/Writer combination, I am having trouble with the reader part.  Given the following declaration

```
public class Jsr367EnumProvider<T extends Enum> implements
                                                MessageBodyReader<T>,
                                                MessageBodyWriter<T>
```

Works but there's a warning saying that `Enum` is raw.  So to fix it I tried to put in `Enum<?>`

However that would yield an error in my `readFrom` method

```
@Override
public T readFrom(final Class<T> type,
    final Type genericType,
    final Annotation[] annotations,
    final MediaType mediaType,
    final MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
    final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException,
        WebApplicationException {

    // TODO support other encodings using the HTTP Header
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A")) {
        return (T) Enum.valueOf(type, s.next());
    }

}
```

Which also warns of an unchecked cast.  Is there a way around this without resorting to `@SupressWarnings`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not. Recall the signature of the method which you're trying to cast:

`Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`

Strictly speaking on the code you've provided, you cannot get rid of the warning. So suppress it, but follow good practices, such as what's prescribed in *Effective Java 2nd Edition: Item 24: Eliminate unchecked warnings:*

> - Eliminate every unchecked warning that you can.
> - If you can't eliminate a warning, and you can prove that the code that provoked the warning is typesafe, then (and only then) suppress the warning with  `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation.
> - Always use the `SuppressWarning` annotation on the smallest scope possible.
> - Every time you use an `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotation, add a comment saying why it's safe to do so.